# How can I share common formatting between Google Documents?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

I have a folder of about 20 Lesson Plans in Google Documents. Although I used an initial template with a bunch of custom formatting for *Heading 1*, *Heading 2*, etc. I now want to tweak the styles.  Is there a reasonable way to sync the formatting between documents?

In other words, I want designate one document as a Master, and propagate the styles to other documents.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, this seems impossible. I tried to see if I could create a script that would copy paragraph heading styles from one document to another, but there seems to be no API for getting style attributes for a heading style.

There *might* be a slight chance you could get something working by using only custom styles, that is, defining your very own Heading styles, for example, and have a script copy those styles from a master document to slave documents. However, once you depend on the pre-defined Heading styles in any of your custom styles, you're out of luck. In any case, using such a system will take a lot of discipline when using styles, so I don't think any such solution will be very practical.

If anyone wants to work further on this, I have shared [a folder on my Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_ea1NXBTibYNXIxb2NwUG9Gakk&usp=sharing).

Comment: I would be happy enough to put some work into the master document, but looking at your answer and the comments in your code, it sounds  like, even if we got it working, it would still be overly fragile.  So sad, it seems like such an obvious use case - it boggles the mind why Google doesn't add a feature like this.